# Non-iAd App Submission Problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, app-store-connect

I'm tring to submit my app to the App Store, but I keep running into the same problem.

When I go to iTunes Connect and click "Manage Your Applications", I get a window that says "You have no Applications Uploaded."

So, I assume I need to add a new application, so I click "Add New Application".

However, when I do so, I get the following error: "You have no eligible Bundle IDs".

I've heard this is an iAd problem, but I don't need iAds in my app, I just want to submit it.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Are you using the Application Loader?  As of 7/22 you must use the Application Loader, binary uploads thru iTunes Connect are no longer accepted.

Comment: Thanks for responding- I tried to use Application Loader, but it said "No eligible applications were found: ... you must first log in to iTunes Connect and provide information about the application you will be adding."

Comment: If that's the problem, then how do I "provide" that information?

Comment: "Make sure the status of your app in iTunes Connect is Waiting for Upload before you submit your binary through Application Loader." from Apple's email on this.  They also provided this link to an [FAQ](http://www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/faqs)

Comment: That's the problem though... how can I see my app in iTunes Connect if I haven't added it yet?

Comment: You can add all the meta data without uploading the binary in iTC.

Comment: The problem is, I can't see the status of my app because iTC doesn't know about it, I guess... how do I add the meta deta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to visit the [Provisioning Portal](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/bundles/index.action) and add at least 1 app id first.